# Avoiding form validation enforced checks on non-required fields in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I have an e-mail field which is -not- required in my form validation. It should be able to be left blank. However, when I use the "valid_email" parameter of the form validation's set_rules, it still gives an error message that the e-mail is not valid when it's not supposed to check this if the field has not been filled out.

Comment: Please post your relevant code.

Answer (score 4):

**Rule Reference**

Checking the [reference](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference) on this matter tells us the following regarding the `valid email` rule:

> Returns FALSE if the form element does not contain a valid email address.

This would be true of an empty field, as well as a field with bad values.

**Trimming**

I notice in the examples provided by CodeIgniter that emails are usually not only required, and required to be valid emails, but are also trimmed. This may result in a different outcome.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
```

During the validation process, the following is considered:

```
// If the field is blank, but NOT required, no further tests are necessary
if ( ! in_array('required', $rules) AND is_null($postdata))
```

It may be the case that the contents of your email field aren't exactly *null*, and are therefore raising flags with the `valid_email` requirement.

**Possible Related Bugs**

Three months prior to the date of this answer there was discussion on bitbucket regarding this very topic. The discussion can be viewed at <strike>https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/issue/117/input-fields-are-automatically-required</strike>.

It's stated that using array-syntax (see below) in the markup results in similar errors even when the `required` rule is not set:

```
<input name="user[email]" />
```

Further discussion, and patches, are available here, [http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/159243](http://web.archive.org/web/20120530001055/http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/159243). One suggest patch that seems to solve the issue is to replace the `is_null()` call with `empty()` in the aforementioned code:

So the following:

```
if ( ! in_array('required', $rules) AND is_null($postdata))
```

Becomes:

```
if ( ! in_array('required', $rules) AND empty($postdata))
```

Comment: Your answer helped me so much. I was getting that behaviour with array-based names, and substituting the is_null with empty really did the thing. No more pointless checks

Comment: I was wondering if you could fix your last two links.  They are giving 404 errors.  With the sale of CodeIgniter, a lot of content has been lost or moved.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky I was able to find a cached copy of the thread through wayback, but the repo on bitbucket has long been deleted and I am unable to salvage a copy. Apologies.

Comment: No worries, I found and fixed the bug anyway.  I just figured you'd want to fix or remove the bad links though.  FYI, the mentioned line that needs fixing is located in `system/libraries/Form_validation.php` and can be fixed by overriding the offending function with your own "extended" version located in `application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php`.   [See the "Extending Native Libraries" section here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

Answer (score 4):

according to https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html?highlight=validation#id28

use `permit_empty` this

> Allows the field to receive an empty array, empty string, null or
> false

so your code looks like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'permit_empty|valid_email');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to appreciate that `''` IS not a valid e-mail address. If you don't want to validate some postdata and don't care if it's empty, you shouldn't set a rule on it, like so:

```
if($this->input->post('item'))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('item', 'Item number', 'trim|alpha_numeric|max_length[30]');
}
```

In this case, if there is nothing submitted for 'item', no rule is added, so the rest of the data would go on to validation stage etc. as normal.

Comment: In this case the `!empty()` statement isn't necessary, since according to documentation, `$this->input->post('something')` is equal to `if ( ! isset($_POST['something']))
{
    $something = FALSE;
}
else
{
    $something = $_POST['something'];
}`

Comment: Thanks, I've clarified my answer.